Exercise with fundamental theorem of calculus: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_0^x \left( \int_1^{sin(t)} \sqrt{1 + u^4} du \right) dt = ?$
$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_0^x \left( \int_1^{sin(t)} \sqrt{1 + u^4} du \right) dt = ?$
I proceeded as follows, applying the fundamental theorem of calculus two times:
$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{sin(x)} \sqrt{1 + u^4} du = \sqrt{1 + sin^4(x)} cos(x)$
Am I right?

I think, you are right.

Let $F(u)$ be an antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+u^4}$ and $G(t)$ be an antiderivative of $F(\sin t)$. Then,
$$\int_0^x\int_1^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4}dudt=\int_0^x(F(\sin t)-F(1))dt\\=G(x)-F(1)x-G(0)$$
And
$$(G(x)-F(1)x-G(0))''=(F(\sin x)-F(1))'=\sqrt{1+\sin^4x}\cos x$$
